# Custom post type single page returns 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, single

I have a custom post type called `slide`. It has content and some custom fields. I want **WP** to show the `single.php` theme or `single-slide.php` theme when the user clicks the slide single page link. the problem I have is that **WP** throws 404 error, when I want to see the single slide page.

here is my code in `functions.php`:

```
function create_slide_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'افزودن', 'i2sa' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'افزودن اسلاید جدید', 'i2sa' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'اسلاید جدید', 'i2sa' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'ویرایش اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'نمایش اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'همه اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'جستجوی اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'اسلایدهای مادر:', 'i2sa' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'اسلایدی پیدا نشد.', 'i2sa' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'اسلایدی در زباله دان پیدا نشد.', 'i2sa' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => "اسلایدهای شرکت i2sa",
        'public'             => true,
        'exclude_from_search'=> true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'  => false,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'slide' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'slide', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_slide_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You should set your `publicly_queryable` argument to `true` when registering your custom post type.

**TAKE NOTE**: Add [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules), refresh the page once or twice and REMOVE IT IMMEDIATELY. You SHOULD NOT keep `flush_rewrite_rules()` unless under the provisions as in the codex.

> this is an expensive operation so it should only be used when absolutely necessary

Comment: Oh wow, that worked here, too. That was completely non-obvious. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Yes! Finally after doing both it worked.

Comment: `flush_rewrite_rules()` was it for me - nice one!

Comment: You can simply try to go to Settings > Permalinks and click save without changing anything. If you don't want to edit your code and are looking for a 'hopefully' quick fix

Answer (score 24):

Flush the rewrite rule from dashboard -> Settings->Permalink page. Click on save button and then check your slide details page. It will work now. Otherwise you can write this code `flush_rewrite_rules()` in your `create_slide_post_type()` function. See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)

Comment: Clicking on the save button in Permlinks worked for me. After I moved the site to a production server, all the custom post type links were breaking. This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Just clicking save in Permalinks also worked for me.

Comment: Saving the permalinks works. But please do not add `flush_rewrite_rules()` after `register_post_type()` calls in production code (i.e. inside `create_slide_post_type`). Use the plugin-activation hook or an option value to determine that you added a new post type

Answer (score 11):

Refresh your permalinks. Go to Admin->Settings->Permalinks and hit Save. It refreshes your permalinks and should help, especially if you are changing rewrite *( 'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'slide' ),)*

Comment: did it for me - thank you

Answer (score 4):

You should set the following in your virtualhost apache:

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

Then, refresh your permalinks: wp-admin->settings->permalinks.
That's worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. Now I at least know that the problem is in my apache configuration and not the code.